# Bringing back Android Fragments in its initial state

Tags: android, initialization, fragment

I am trying to write an app with two Fragments. The top fragment 'A' contains two EditText fields for user id and password.  The bottom fragment 'B' contains a Login button.  The first time I sign into the app, things work exactly the way it should and the app proceeds to display another fragment 'C' which has replaced fragment 'A'. The bottom fragment 'B' now displays a Log off button. When I click this button, I get back fragment A to replace C and the user id and password fields are displayed.

The problem that I am facing is during the second run.  The fragment A still retains the original values for user id and password from the first run.  If I use the EditText's getText.clear or setText("") methods, the fields become empty, but then while I press the Login button, it complains that the fields are empty even though I have keyed in values.

Could you please tell me how to bring back Fragment A in its initial state?  TIA
Here's the code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
showLogon(btnLeft, btnRight, fragmentTransaction);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();

private void showLogon(final Button btnLeft, final Button btnRight, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
//EditText uid = ((EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editUserid));
//uid.setText("");
//EditText pwd = ((EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editPassword));
//pwd.setText("");
Login login = new Login();
//getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.topFrame, login).commit();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.topFrame, login);
btnLeft.setText("Login");
btnRight.setVisibility(View.GONE);
btnRight.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: please post some code for us to look into

Comment: @Atish Agrawal I have added the relevant code now

Comment: @user3763182 I tested out your suggestion, but it still won't forget the values from the initial run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did a "getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userid));" from fragment B, it was picking up the previous value, but if I do a "getView().findViewById(R.id.userid));" from fragment A, then it picks up the correct value. R.id.userid resides in the fragment A layout.  If I do a getView from fragment B, I get a NullPointerException.  So I declared a text watcher on Fragment A's edittext that loaded a member variable that was accessible to Fragment B, and that seemed to have resolved the problem.  If there's a better way to do it, please let me know.  Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

when you replace fragment c with fragment a create a new instance of fragment a
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.llContainer, new FragmentA()).commit();